# Https not working properly Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, multisite

Not that long ago i let my hosting add an ssl certificate to one of my domains. 
There are now multiple problems with it.

**Problem 1**
When i visit the website without adding www,http or anything else (just the domain) it doesnt redirect to https it just goes to the domain name. for example if i go to test.com it wont add the https.

**Problem 2**
When i visit my domain name with https in front it shows me the green https mark for like 1 mili second and then it dissapears again and tells me the site is not secured when i click on the information icon next to the url.

**Problem 3**

When i go to my wp-admin it shows me the green https signs like it should normally.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Im using a multi site network with the domain mapping plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**
If your >Settings>General is displaying https:// in both site Address & Wordpress Address - should be fine, but you could also edit your **wpconfig.php** file and add

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.yourdomain.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://www.yourdomain.com' );
```

Additionally, if you have access to your **.htaccess** file, you could add:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Problem 2:**
Sounds like a "Mixed content" problem. If any images (as example) are hard coded to http://, it can cause this issue.

Simple to fix though, 
install a plugin like "**SSL Insecure Content Fixer**" (there are others also). Then under your Settings menu, you will now see a "SSL Insecure Content" menu - under that, choose the "Capture" setting (2nd last), and at bottom under HTTPS detection, choose best option (e.g. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO) and save changes - you should be good to go!

**Problem 3:**
If I am correct, this is not a problem - once you fix mixed content - all should be fine...

I hope this helps point you in the right direction...

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply most of the problems are now fixed. Problem one is .. well still a problem sadly. Everytime i go to the domain without https in fron it will go to the domain without https in front. what i want is when i visit the domain like test.com it must redirect to (https://)test.com

Comment: DNS? You should be able to setup "*.domain.com" as a C Name pointing  to your main www. (www.domain.com)... You can also add code in your htaccess:

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]